# Crystal Report : Checked on checkbox for each row in table

Tags: crystal-reports

How to display checked box if we take data from database?

I have a RankingTable in database that save a rating achievement such as

[image: RankingTable in Database]

So from this table taken from database, i want to display in crystal report like this:

[image: Table display in report]

I try to use the formula below for each checkbox however it is not working as only the first checkbox are functioning, while the other checkbox only display chr(168)

```
    IF({RankingTable.question_id}='1' AND {RangkingTable.rank} = '1') THEN  
      Chr(254)  
    ELSE  
      Chr(168)
```

This is my first two questions, as you can see, only the first checkbox is working, while the other checkbox, it become false:

[image: Result table]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `it is not working`? Please edit your question and add that information...

Comment: hi, already edit it

Comment: `IF({RankingTable.question_id}='1' ...` --> why do you 'hard-code' the id `1` ?

Comment: is there other way so that i make sure that the checkbox is for question 1?

Comment: Crystal Reports formulas work on a per-record basis. Usually they shouldn't refer to a single database record(-id). Remove the part `{RankingTable.question_id}='1' AND ` from your formula and see what happens...

Comment: It's not working as it will only tick if rank is 'n/a'  {IF{RangkingTable.rank} = 'n/a' THEN}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217098/discussion-between-haya-and-matsnow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think now i know the problem which i should separate the rank instead of just in one column 'rank', i create one column for one rank as said by @MatSnow, it work on per record basis, so then i can use this formula and get the result just like what i want

```
IF({RankingTable.tb}='Yes')THEN
    Chr(254)
ELSE
    Chr(168)
```

[image: Result after implemented different column]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the font to Wingdings.

The CHR(168) and CHR(254) ASCII codes do not create the checkbox graphics by default because these are the ASCII codes for Diaeresis and Latin Small Letter Thorn.  However, if you change the font to Wingdings, then print these ASCII characters the font will change them into a Ballot Box and a Checked Ballot Box.

Here is a link for reference that details the exact steps if you need further assistance.

https://blogs.sap.com/2012/05/18/how-to-display-a-check-box-and-a-radio-button-in-crystal-report-2011/

Comment: thankyou, however i have a different problem, i'm still appreciate your answer